# How to use hardware accelerated video encoding of GStreamer on Android?

Tags: android, gstreamer, hardware-acceleration, encoder

I am trying to design hardware accelerated video encoder based on Android. I have done research for some time but I did not find much useful.

Anyway, I saw the Gstreamer (http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/). It is said this can provide hardware video encoder. However, after I read the manual, I found nothing about encoder.

Does anyone know about this stuff? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be dependent on your hardware. What device are you running on?

If your processor contains an IP core that implements video encoding/decoding, the manufacturer needs to either offer a driver so you can call this hardware, or ideally go a step further and offer a specific plugin for GStreamer that does it.

For example, the Freescale i.MX6 processor (used in the [Wandboard](http://wandboard.org/) and [CuBox](http://www.solid-run.com/cubox-i-main-page/)) has a driver maintained by Freescale: https://github.com/Freescale/gstreamer-imx

TI OMAP processors have support: http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/GStreamer, also see TI [Distributed Codec Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Codec_Engine).

Broadcom processors have support: https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/gstreamer0.10-crystalhd

There are also several standard interfaces to video accelerator hardware, including [VDPAU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Decode_and_Presentation_API_for_Unix), [VAAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Acceleration_API), and [OpenMax IL](https://www.khronos.org/openmax/il/). If your processor is not one of the above, someone may have written a driver that maps one of these standard interfaces to your hardware.

The Rasberry Pi is apparently supported by the OpenMax IL plugin: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/releases/gst-omx/1.0.0.html

If you don't know whether your processor is supported, I'd search for the name and various combinations of "VDPAU", "VAAPI", etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are a wide variety of encoding options in Gstreamer to take a raw stream and encode it.  Pretty much any element ending in "enc" can be used to do the encoding.  Here is a good example of a few encoding pipelines:

https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php/TVP5146_GStreamer_example_pipelines

With that said, I'd caution that video encoding is extremely hardware intensive.  I would also look at getting a special purpose hardware encoder and to not do software encoding via GStreamer if you're stream is a robust size.

Comment: Thanks! So is this one a hardware acceleration one?

Comment: Not sure if I'm understanding your question.  If by "hardware encoding" you mean that there's specific h/w doing the encoding or on the CPU, then GStreamer is mainly a library that allows general purpose CPUs to do encoding, but its done in software.  There are a few options of doing hardware encoding with GStreamer, see http://www.jumpnowtek.com/?option=com_content&view=article&id=81:gumstix-dsp-gstreamer&catid=35:gumstix&Itemid=67

Comment: But is there a plugin that allows us to offload hardware encoding to the GPU?